# AHK Struggles to Enter Values into ComboBox

Tags: autohotkey

I am writing an AHK script to automate data entry into a GUI form.  There is a drop-down box with a few hundred entries.  I know the value I want to select and when I manually type in the number the combo box changes to the appropriate value.  When I send the same string in AHK (using Send) it chooses the first item on the list.  I have played around with various values of SetKeyDelay (-1 through 2000).

```
SetKeyDelay 1000
Send %ItemNumber%
SetKeyDelay -1
```

Any suggestions here?

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried other send modes? (Like SendInput, SendPlay, etc...)

Also, if it's a standard Windows combobox, it might be more precise to use messages (like [CB_SETCURSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775899)).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a line up top that was messing me up:

```
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
```

SendInput ignores the value of SetKeyDelay;  the above line was converting all of my "Send"s to "SendInput"s

Thanks-

Jonathan